# How to add vat to this invoice?

Tags: tables, invoice

I'm using the invoice document class. However, I do not possess the knowledge required to add VAT to it... Can anyone help me with this? I want to add 25 % of the total cost and it should display like this:

[image: example]

So, the final result should look like this. Don't mind the different currencies and wrong numbers. This is instead of the "Balance Due" post.

[image: final]

"To pay" should display price without vat times 1.25, but I don't know how to program this.

Here is the .tex file

```
\documentclass{invoice} % Use the custom invoice class (invoice.cls)

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil % Company providing the invoice
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ % Your address and contact information
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ % Invoice date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF EXPENSES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} % Each separate billing day includes the date, the number of hours and the hourly rate
\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}
\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}
\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{2}{80}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{1}{80}

\subtotal % Prints a subtotal, can be used multiple times

\feetype{Hosting Expenses} % Fee category description

\feerow{Web Hosting: October, 2012}{60} % A flat fee service, note there is no hourly rate for this

\end{invoiceTable}

\end{document}
```

And here's the .cls file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Copyright (c) 2011 Trey Hunner                                          %
%                                                                          %
%  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining   %
%  a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the         %
%  "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including     %
%  without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,     %
%  distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to      %
%  permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to   %
%  the following conditions:                                               %
%                                                                          %
%  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be          %
%  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.         %
%                                                                          %
%  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,         %
%  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF      %
%  MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND                   %
%  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE  %
%  LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION  %
%  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION   %
%  WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.         %
%                                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{invoice}

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=0.79in,vmargin=0.79in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty} % No page numbers
\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} % Double rules look like one thick one

% Command for setting a default hourly rate
\newcommand{\feetype}[1]{
  \textbf{#1}
  \\
}

% Counters for totaling up hours and dollars
\newcounter{hours} \newcounter{subhours} \newcounter{cost} \newcounter{subcost}
\setcounter{hours}{0} \setcounter{subhours}{0} \setcounter{cost}{0} \setcounter{subcost}{0}

% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %

% Returns the total of counter
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}

% Create an invoice table
\newenvironment{invoiceTable}{
% Create a new row from title, unit quantity, unit rate, and unit name
\newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
     ##1 & \formatNumber{##2} ##4 & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}
% Create a new row from title and expense amount
\newcommand*{\feerow}[2]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
     ##1 & & \$\formatNumber{##2} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{1}\formatNumber{\cost}%
     \\
}

\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotalStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotal}{
     \hline
     \@ifstar
     \subtotalStar%
     \subtotalNoStar%
}

% Create a new row from date and hours worked (use stored fee type and hourly rate)
\newcommand*{\hourrow}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{hours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
    \addtocounter{subhours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
    \unitrow{##1}{##2}{##3}{hours}%
}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r r r }
\hline
{\bf Description of Services} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Unit Price} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Amount} \\*
\hline\hline
\endhead
}{
    \hline\hline\hline
    {\bf Balance Due} & & & {\bf \$\total{cost}} \\
    \end{longtable}
}
```

The code generates this pdf: http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/miscellaneous/3/invoice.pdf

Comment: Have you seen the [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) package?

Comment: I have seen the invoice package, but I like the above better, it's much clearer I think. I'm also thinking that it's not very difficult to multiply the total cost by 1.25, but evidently I don't know how to.

Comment: There's nothing in your example file that's similar to the image you're showing.

Comment: No, there isn't. I should make this clearer. Instead of "Balance Due", I want it to look like the picture above. I've edited my original post. Don't mind the different currencies and wrong numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I added the taxes. Here you take a look.
https://github.com/treyhunner/invoices/pull/3

Regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To make your answer more transparent, and more useful, it would be helpful if you posted the code right inside the answer, rather than providing a link to an external site.